# migration error when update a value on postgresSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, backend

i'm having a problem, i'm creating a system of like to my application, but when a try to update the field "likes" that is an array i receive this error
`execution (default) UPDATE "audios" SET "likes"=$1, "updated_at"=$2 WHERE "id" = $3 malformed array literal: "The id"`
and I don't know where's the problem, i've says many post but anyone says what is the correct way to do the model of array on sequelize postgres, i guess that's the problem

and this is my Model configs

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from "sequelize"

class Audio extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
        path: Sequelize.STRING,
        url: {
          type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
          get(){
            return `http://localhost:3000/product-file/${this.path}`
          }
        },
        likes: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      }
    )
    return this
  }
}
export default Audio
```

my update system

```
async update(request, response) {
      const likes = Audio.likes
      console.log(likes)
    try {

  const { id } = request.params
  const likes = request.userId

  await Audio.update(
    {
      likes
    },
    {
      where: { id }
    }
  )

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message)
  return response.status(500).json('server error')
}

    return response.json({ ok: true })
  }`
```

and the migration column the i create

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
   await queryInterface.addColumn('audios', 'likes', {
     type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING)
    })
  },

  async down (queryInterface) {
   await queryInterface.removeColumn('audios', 'likes')
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, data and error messages as text, not links to paintings of them. You can [edit] your question and [use formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: "*update the field "likes" that is an array*" - `likes: Sequelize.STRING` disagrees

Comment: @Bergi so i need change my model? put `likes: Sequelize.ARRAY`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure data types in a migration and a model shoudl be the same in most cases.

Comment: @Anatoly in the Model i need put like: `likes: Sequelize.ARRAY`? I think I need to specify what I'm going to get in the array, but I don't know how to specify that, any ideas?

Comment: @Maycomcosta Why not just `Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING)`, exactly like in your migration?

Comment: @Bergi cause, when i do this i get the error `values.map is not a function`

Comment: @Maycomcosta Is `const likes = request.userId` actually an array?

Comment: @Bergi I already take this, was a test